# Hadoop 2.5.1 Windows 8 Cygwin Namenode class Error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure Hadoop 2.5.1 on my windows machine using cygwin.
But whenever i try to run the command

> hdfs namenode -format

the following error occurs

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

I have set the JAVA_HOME as

> H:\cygwin\usr\local\Java

both in bashrc as well as in hadoop-env.sh.
Can anyone help me as which part I might be going wrong at ???

Comment: Why not http://hortonworks.com/blog/install-hadoop-windows-hortonworks-data-platform-2-0/ ...

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I have the same problem, however I solved other problems I had, on Windows with Cygwin you have to:

1. Make sure you install Java JDK in a folder that does not contain white space
2. Keep path closer to the root `C:\`
3. With Cygwin C:\ is translated as `/cygdrive/c/` 
   NOTE that the (**slash**) must be Linux-style **/** instead of Microsoft-style **\  (back-slash)**
4. Edit the .bashrc file located C:\cygwin\home\username\.bashrc

   export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program_Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71

   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

   export M2_HOME=/cygdrive/c/maven

   export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

   export Platform=x64

   export HADOOP_HOME=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/hadoop

   export HADOOP_INSTALL=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/hadoop

   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin

   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin

   export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

   export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

   export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

   export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

   export HADOOP_CONFIG_DIRECTORY=/cygdrive/c/hadoop/etc/hadoop

Good luck!